# What is the derivative of $x^T A A^T x$ with respect to $A$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

What is the derivative of $x^T A A^T x$ with respect to $A$?

Where $x$ is a vector, and $A$ is a matrix.

**Attempt:**

Writing $B = AA^T$, if I differentiate $x^T B x$ with respect to $B$, I get $xx^T$. Then, using the chain rule, I would have to differentiate $B$ with respect to $A$. My guess is that that gives us $A$.

So the final answer should be $xx^TA$ but I have no idea if I am correct or why.

Comment: The first fact to consider is that your function is $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, so the derivative should have the form of a $n\times n$ matrix. The second is that this function depends on $x$, so it is natural for the derivative to depend also on ir. Third, try to look at explicit variations like $f(A+\epsilon H)$ and look for the linear terms and easy kinds of $H$, as these should correspond to the terms of the matrix you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your function in terms of the Frobenius product $f = x\,x^T : A\,A^T$.

Then taking the derivative is simple. Just expand the differential until you isolate $dA$ on the RHS.
$$ \eqalign {
df &= x\,x^T : d(A\,A^T) \cr
   &= x\,x^T : (dA\,A^T + A\,dA^T) \cr
   &= (x\,x^T : dA\,A^T) + (x\,x^T : A\,dA^T) \cr
   &= (x\,x^T A : dA) + (A^T x\,x^T : dA^T) \cr
   &= (x\,x^T A : dA) + (x\,x^T A : dA) \cr
   &= 2(x\,x^T A) : dA \cr
}$$
On the fifth line I used the fact that $A:B = A^T:B^T$.

So the derivative is $$\frac {\partial f} {\partial A} = 2(x\,x^T A)$$
which is almost what you thought, except for that factor of 2.