# Is the derivative of $\pmb x^\top (I+GB)^{-1} (I+GB)^{-\top}\pmb x$ with respect to $B$ a 4th-order tensor?

Tags: derivatives, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis

Is the derivative of $\pmb x^\top (I+GB)^{-\top} (I+GB)^{-1}\pmb x$  with respect to $B$ a 4th-order tensor?

Where $\pmb x$ is a vector, and $B$ is a matrix.

I followed the procedures in [What is the derivative of $x^T A A^T x$ with respect to $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992691/what-is-the-derivative-of-xt-a-at-x-with-respect-to-a) and arrived at $2\pmb x\pmb x^\top(I+GB)^{-1} : -(I+GB)^{-\top}⊗(I+GB)G$, with the ":" sign denoting the Frobenious product. But here is the problem: the function is from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which implies that the derivative w.r.t. $B$ should be a matrix instead of a tensor!

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
A=\LR{I+GB}^{-1} \qiq dA = -A\LR{G\,dB}A \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of the function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x^TA^TAx \\
  &= xx^T:A^TA \\
d\phi &= xx^T:2\sym{A^TdA} \\
  &= 2Axx^T:dA \\
  &= -2Axx^T:A\LR{G\,dB}A \\
  &= -2G^TA^TAxx^TA^T:dB \\
\grad{\phi}{B} &= -2G^TA^TAxx^TA^T \\
}$$
So the gradient is a matrix, not a tensor.

In this derivation I have utilized the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
and the `sym()` operator
$$\sym X = \frac{X+X^T}2$$

Answer (score 0):

What you did was right: The function is indeed from $\Bbb R^{n×n}$ to $\Bbb R$, and the derivative with respect to $B$ is indeed a matrix. The multiplication by $\pmb x$ and $\pmb x^\top$, in each case, effectively reduces the dimension of the tensor by $1$. Also, note that a matrix is a two-dimensional tensor.